# What are the stocking time differences relating to the rating of bitizens?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've recently started accepting bitizens with a rating of 8 now to fill my stores until I find a dream job, as 9's are quite hard to come by. I'm just wondering the time difference % wise how much faster each bitizen is from ratings 1 through 9. I'm wondering this because sometimes I find it really hard to fill up my store but 6's and 7's are VERY common. So the real question is, is it worth it to get and 8/9 or settle with a 6/7 while waiting for a dream job to come along.

This information is very important for me as I also need to calculate whether it's worth it to say have a dream job as a low rating of say 2/3 or have a normal worker of 8/9 as maybe even with the x2 stock it's not worth it as say bitizen can stock more than twice as fast with an 8/9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for restock time appears to be as follows:

```
Time (minutes) = N * (1 - S/100) / 10
```

Where `N` is the base stock amount for the good in question (the amount of stock at Rank 1, i.e. no upgrades) and `S` is the sum of the appropriate skills of the bitizens in the store. I think fractions of a minute are dropped, but the minimum is 1 minute.

Therefore the difference in stocking times between two bitizens whose skill difference is 1 will be ~1% for all three positions in the level. Given that, it looks like a Dream Job worker is always preferable to a higher-skill non-Dream Job worker.